# Spurious wakeups on condition_variable with g++ and clang++

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, c++11, pthreads

Take the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  mutex m;
  condition_variable c;

  bool fired = false;
  int i = 0;

  // This thread counts the times the condition_variable woke up.
  // If no spurious wakeups occur it should be close to 5.
  thread t([&]() {
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
    while (!fired) {
      c.wait_for(l, chrono::milliseconds(100));
      ++i;
    }
  });

  // Here we wait for 500ms, then signal the other thread to stop
  this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
  {
    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
    fired = true;
    c.notify_all();
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  t.join();
}
```

Now, when I build this using `clang++ -std=c++11 -pthread foo.cpp` everything is fine, it outputs `4` on my machine. When I build it with `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread foo.cpp` however I get something very large *every* time, e.g. `81513`. I realize the number of spurious wakeups is undefined, but I was surprised to see it so high.

Additional information: When I replace the `wait_for` by a simple `wait` both clang and g++ output `0`.

Is this a bug / feature in g++? Why is it even different from clang? Can I get it to behave more reasonably?

Also: `gcc version 4.7.3 (Debian 4.7.3-4)`.

Comment: A good thing to know would be which standard library you use in the clang case. It runs fine with gcc 4.8.1 on my system btw. (won't compile with 4.7.3). stracing all threads might lead to futher useful information.

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 gives: 4

Comment: clang uses the same standard library as g++, i don't have libc++ on that system. it's a debian testing btw.

Comment: Fwiw, Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28), and I likewise get 4, just as your clang does.

Comment: [G++-4.7.3 on Coliru outputs "4" for this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/624d70c935139b70), so there's some other variable here than the compiler version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get g++-4.8 running, and the problem is gone. Very weird, seems like a bug in g++-4.7.3, although I wasn't able to reproduce it on another machine.